# how to change the format of a array to collection as each item in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have an array of collections like below :

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => Collection {#990 ▶}
  1 => Collection {#1109 ▶}
  2 => Collection {#1221 ▶}
  3 => Collection {#1331 ▶}
  4 => Collection {#1442 ▶}
  5 => Collection {#1554 ▶}
  6 => Collection {#1664 ▶}
  7 => Collection {#1775 ▶}
  8 => Collection {#1887 ▶}
]
```

i want to make this a single collection and make each collection as 1 item of that collection now what i tried is `collect($f)` but i get the result as below :

```
Collection {#1443 ▼
  #items: array:9 [▼
    0 => Collection {#990 ▶}
    1 => Collection {#1109 ▶}
    2 => Collection {#1221 ▶}
    3 => Collection {#1331 ▶}
    4 => Collection {#1442 ▶}
    5 => Collection {#1554 ▶}
    6 => Collection {#1664 ▶}
    7 => Collection {#1775 ▶}
    8 => Collection {#1887 ▶}
  ]
}
```

now i want to know how can i make this 1 collection and make all those 8 collection as items of that collection like below :

```
Collection {#990 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => RoomPricingHistory {#971 ▶}
    1 => RoomPricingHistory {#971 ▶}
    2 => RoomPricingHistory {#971 ▶}
    3 => RoomPricingHistory {#971 ▶}
    4 => RoomPricingHistory {#971 ▶}

  ]
}
```

thanks

Comment: So you have 8 collections that contain each a single RoomPricingHistory?

Comment: Do you think pluck() function may work for your use-case ?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-pluck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a collection of collections, you can use [flatten](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-flatten) to get all elements of the underlying collections in the parent collection.

```
collect($f)->flatten(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after.

1. **First, using artisan I'll make a collection of collections. Each collection has a single element array `[1]`**

```php
$ php artisan tinker
>>> $a = collect(1)
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3205
     all: [
       1,
     ],
   }
>>> collect(array($a,$a,$a,$a,$a,$a,$a))
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3218
     all: [
       Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3205
         all: [
           1,
         ],
       },
       Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3205},
       Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3205},
       Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3205},
       Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3205},
       Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3205},
       Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3205},
     ],
   }
```

2. **Now, to get only an array of those elements, I use the `flatten()` method.**

```
>>> collect(array($a,$a,$a,$a,$a,$a,$a))->flatten()
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3220
     all: [
       1,
       1,
       1,
       1,
       1,
       1,
       1,
     ],
   }
```

The `flatten` method accepts an optional depth paramether. Read more about it in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-flatten)